# 404 redirect with multiple segments not working

Tags: conditionals, 404, no-results

I have a page on my site: mysite.com/index.php/staff/staff-bio/john-smith

I'm using this 404 redirect:

```
{if no_results OR segment_2 != "staff-bio" OR segment_4 != ""}{redirect="404"}{/if}
```

On a related note, I'm using the require_entry="yes" option in my staff-bio template.

This redirect statement catches the problem it staff-bio is not segment 2, and if extra segments are added to the end, but if I were to change "john-smith" to just "john" in the url, or enter some other invalid path, it doesn't redirect.  It just goes to a blank template page.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug on the no_results conditional, to me.

May I suggest you something? Let's change your approach to this. Look at the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html#rendering-stages). You should take advantage of the parsing order and do not let your code run if you can avoid. So, use simple conditionals around the channel:entries variable pair.

This way, in the two first situations, the parsing process will pass right from the stage 13, **simple conditionals**, to the 20, **redirect variable**:

```
{if segment_4}{redirect="404"}{/if}
{if segment_2 != "staff-bio"}{redirect="404"}{/if}
{if segment_2 == "staff-bio"}
    {if segment_4 == ""}
        {exp:channel:entries [...] require_entry="yes"}
            {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
        {/exp:cahnnel:entries}
    {/if}
{/if}
```

Comment: ok, so now I'm getting error messages.  If I delete the last set of conditionals it doesn't give errors, but then its back to not redirecting again.

Comment: here's the first error:  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Creating default object from empty value

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 2508

Comment: and 2 more errors as well.    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 408

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 2

Comment: there appears to be a bug about this particular issue...https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18304

Comment: Feel free to open a chat room and to show me your code there. We can try to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Robson's suggestion is on the money. Another approach would be to use the awesome [IfElse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse) add-on so parsing is less of an issue.

Using your example, it would look something like this:

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}    
    {if segment_4 != "" || segment_2 != "staff-bio"}
        {redirect="404"}
    {if:elseif segment_2 == "staff_bio"}
        {if segment_4 == ""}
            {exp:channel:entries [...] require_entry="yes"}
                {no_results}{redirect="404"}{/no_results}
            {/exp:cahnnel:entries}
        {/if}
    {/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

I'm not 100% sure you even need that condition in the if:elseif part, but it's a place to start. :)

Comment: Hei, Angie! Since your answer complements mine, move it into my answer. Feel free to improve it. I really prefer to use just the addons I really need, but its good to show all options.

Comment: If I could mark 2 answers as correct I would!  Not sure which approach I'll use yet, but this gives me something to chew on.  Thank you!

Comment: Hey Robson, no worries! I agree on using just add-ons you need but IfElse is super cool. :)